# Annotate a book in html format?

Tags: pdf, html

I am using Okular for annotating pdf files (e.g. adding comments, drawing lines, circling text, adding images, ...).

What applications do you recommend to read and annotate books in html? For example, this book http://cvs.sourceforge.net/cvstarballs/cl-cookbook-cvsroot.tar.bz2, from http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/

My OS is Ubuntu 12.04.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have a funny way of doing this, but since you asked~

The answer?

**Google Spreadsheets | Check this out:**

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IEfYx8zclii0ux1nn1flK7aAnPrL0fuVvBqdhOzFPLY/edit#gid=0

Why is this good for annotation? Because I can rightclick any box, and add a comment or a note, or I can just make a cell beside it, and comment there. Finding my comments or notes on this is incredibly easy because of the search feature, and because this is google docs, I can access it anywhere, and collaboratively edit.

**Now the question is; How do you get the books onto here?**

So I actually have two books here; one I ripped from a PDF, and one I took from an HTML. You will need to install Geany to do this efficiently:

```
sudo apt-get install geany
```

The HTML version is usually pretty easy to work with, as newlines aren't given in the middle of sentences, and you don't have to worry about picking up page numbers. So to get started, I'll use a pdf for an example:

1. Open up your book with a PDF viewer; Any viewer which can select or interpret text.
2. Select All:  <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>
3. Paste into Geany.

Now this is where you need to decide how you want to format your book. As you can see from my example, I dedicate 1 line to every sentence, I prefix a space to every sentence in a paragraph that is not the first sentence, I split the paragraphs by an empty cell, and I append a ↩ to every chapter or section.

How do you do this?

a) **Manually** (The stupid way)

or

b) **Regular Expressions**
[image]

**I'll give you a short example.**

Once the text is dumped into geany:

1. Open **Replace**: <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd>
2. Select checkbox, "**Use Regular Expressions**" and "**Case Sensitive**"
3. Search:

   **([a-z]+[.\?!])( [A-Z][a-z ])**

What that searches for broadly is the beginning of a new sentence within a paragraph.

**More Specifically:**

([a-z]+[.\?!]) - The last word being all lowercase, and ending with a period, exclamation point, or question mark.

( [A-Z][a-z ]) - The next word is on the same line, starting with a capital, and having a lowercase or space as the next character.

The Curved Brackets are used to Capture Text (See tutorial link below)

4. Replace:

   **\1\n\2**

**\1** uses the first capture (), and places a newline **\n** between the second capture **\2**. The end result is that nearly all my sentences within a paragraph are separated by a newline, with a space prefixed to them. **The reason why the newline is important, is that this will make it easy to paste into a spreadsheet.**

Now, there is more work to do than that, and this is just a sample of what you may need to do.

**Don't know regex? Don't worry; it takes about an hour to learn:**

http://regexone.com/

Cheers!